# How to get user location, using GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, maps

I need to get user location, when application launched for set marker on Google Map. I found this variant for find user location:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //Get location and unsubscribe
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            ...
        }
   ...
}
```

Such method doesn't always work. Usually, application wait for 30 sec - 2 min. But sometimes this doesn't work and I can't take listener response.

---

How to get user location and take 100% response (if this possibly, when device normal work)?

Comment: *How to get user location and take 100% response?* You can't... There's are situations when it's not available (fx out of satellites range(underground, bad weather, military ops, etc.))

Comment: @Selvin, I update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you wait for the initial "real" location update to complete, you can [get the last location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) known to the device using

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

This doesn't guarantee that you will have the most up-to-date location, but it can hopefully give you something relevant to display in the meantime.

Comment: My problem in that sometimes I can't get result. I have places, which I show in start.

Comment: In that case, I have to agree with @Selvin. There is no way to 100% guarantee a location fix. If you really need to display some kind of location, maybe you can prompt the user to manually enter an address and geocode this into the map marker coordinates. You will have to plan your UX for these kinds of uncertainties.

Comment: I think, that I can't take 100% result. Not I want take this: program will showing progress dialog, after launch. If, after 1 minute, program not fount user location - I propose user input location manually. But, in example, in Georgia, where my friend test program, he didn' take any result in any case!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER. It is less accurate comparing to GPS but it is more available.